# Find $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]\cap \mathbb{C}[(x-1)^2, (x-1)^3]$.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

> Find $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]\cap \mathbb{C}[(x-1)^2, (x-1)^3]$.

I am trying to find the above subring. I would prefer hints more than complete solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably too much of a hint, but I can't think of anything better:

The ring $\mathbb{C}[x^2, x^3]$ is the ring of polynomials with the property that $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Now it is obvious, you are right. I was hoping there was a more constructive solution, in the sense a solution that could be generalized in other cases. If the second generator of the second ring were $(x-1)^3(x-3)$ could you find an answer?

Comment: There probably is something systematic you can do but I'm not sure off hand. I know you can do things like look at rings such as $\mathbb{C}[s,t,x]$ and the ideal $I=(s-x^2, t-x^3)$ and do Gröbner basis calculuations to find $J = \mathbb{C}[s,t] \cap I$ (note $\mathbb{C}[s,t]/J \cong \mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$). Maybe you can work something out along those lines?

Comment: For the specific generator you mention, note that it is actually $(x-1)^4 - 2(x-1)^3$, and after a little work reducing things, you can see that the resulting ring still has $(x-1)^2$ and $(x-1)^3$ in it. I have some vague impression this sort of thing works a lot.